# Odd type value I cannot convert to float

Tags: python

I basically copy pasted census stats from a PDF into a an excel file. The numbers in excel looked chunky and odd. I thought it was the font so I tried to change it but it didn't change anything. I went ahead and saved the file as a CSV and opened it in a Python Jupyter notebook. The files also look 'funny' in Python (see screenshot). I did a dtypes() and it spits dtype('o').

I have no idea what formatting this is but I cannot move forward before I transform this into float numbers. I tried .astype(float) but it throws an error saying that 'ValueError: could not convert string to float'.

I am fairly confused with this odd format. If that helps it was data from a Chinese PDF? Numbers were in 'English'.

[image]

Comment: dtype 'o' means 'object', which for python/pandas is used to indicate strings. Your data is a string that cannot be cast to a float. not sure why this is- could be like a space character between each digit? but the fact that excel is even having trouble, means something weird is going on.

Comment: what happens if you open that csv in notepad or text editor? are there numbers or some other special characters?

Comment: So, just opened it in notepad and does the same thing, it looks odd. The column text looks normal, just like in the jupyter notebook, but that makes sense because I manually typed the columns in excel.

PS: there is no spaces in between

Comment: The data is a string that appears numeric, but cannot be simply converted to `float` because it is using different digit characters - specifically, [full-width digit variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halfwidth_and_Fullwidth_Forms_(Unicode_block)) commonly used in Chinese, Japanese and Korean text. You need to normalize the data first (see the linked duplicate) and then you can proceed normally.